# norms of equidistant vectors

Tags: inequality, euclidean-geometry

Let $E$ be an euclidean vector space and let $x_1,\ldots,x_n$ be vectors in $E$, such that :

$$\forall(i,j)\in \left\{1,\ldots,n\right\}^2,i\neq j\Rightarrow\Vert x_i-x_j\Vert\ge2$$

I want to show that there exists at least an index $i\in \{1,\ldots,n\}$ such that :

$$\Vert x_i\Vert\ge\sqrt{\frac{2(n-1)}{n}}$$

Any hint would be appreciated.

Comment: Duplicate target found [with Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%5CVert%20x_i%5CVert%5Cge%5Csqrt%7B%5Cfrac%7B2(n-1)%7D%7Bn%7D%7D%24)